Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39:py3_runtime' failed
TensorFlow : v2.16.1 
gcc : gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0  
uname: x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04 
bazel : v6.5.0 
Built Tensorflow v2.16.1 from source. bazel test fails with below error:
bazel test -- //tensorflow/...
ERROR: /root/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39/BUILD:36:11: in    interpreter_path attribute of py_runtime rule //tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39:py3_runtime: must be an absolute path.
 ERROR: /root/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39/BUILD:36:11: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39:py3_runtime' failed
Any workaround?
(Couldn't find test suite execution steps in official documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)
